# pyspark convert millisecond timestamp to timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, aws-glue

I am new in spark and i would like to retrieve timestamps in my DF.

> checkpoint actual values
>
> 1594976390070

and i want :

> checkpoint values without ms
>
> 1594976390070 / 1000

Actually i am using this piece of code to cast as timestamp:

```
# Casting dates as Timestamp
for d in dateFields:
    df= df.withColumn(d,checkpoint.cast(TimestampType()))
```

I wonder how to convert it into a simple timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide your column by 1000 and use `F.from_unixtime` to convert to timestamp type:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

for d in dateFields:
    df = df.withColumn(d,
        (checkpoint / F.lit(1000.)).cast('timestamp')
    )
```